# How would I got about implementing an instance of react-wavesurfer not using es6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, audio, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm unfamiliar with es6 and would like to use react-wavesurfer in my project. the documentation is here: https://github.com/mspae/react-wavesurfer but the example use is in es6 and I'm not sure how I would do it in more vanilla js. IE var WaveSurfer = React.createClass etc... any help on how I would embed this in my rails project would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: paste the example's code into https://babeljs.io/repl?

Comment: The most important part of the example in the `render` method. You can just look at it and ignore the rest of code. It is just React component declaration without any specifics, so you can just use `React.createClass` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together an example of how to do this: http://codepen.io/mspae/pen/XdaRZL

(Click on the `Settings` button on the top right and then on `JavaScript` to see which javascript files I included. The order is important if you're not using a module loader)

Note that in most React examples these days – apart from the basic es6 transformation (which brings lots of basic language features) – there is also the JSX transformation (Which translates html style tags into calls to `React.createElement(...`). With the go-to transpiler at the moment – babel – supporting both this is almost always done together, but the two things work independently.

For the difference between the es6 `class MyComponent extends React.Component` syntax and the es5 (read: non-transpiled javascript) `React.createClass({...` API this article is quite informative: https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/

And for information how to use React without JSX I recommend this article: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-reactjs-without-jsx